# undefined reference to cv::Formatter::get(char const*) opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I followed the tutorial [**trainHOG Tutorial**](https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial)  for training Images in OpenCV

I have included all libraries, include files.

I tried running the code on *Win7x64*, *code blocks* IDE, *opencv 2.4.7*
I am getting following errors when I compiled the code :

D:\opencv\build\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_ts247.a(ts_perf.cpp.obj):ts_perf.cpp:(.text.unlikely._ZN2cvlsERSoRKNS_3MatE+0x15)||undefined reference to `cv::Formatter::get(char const*)'|

D:\opencv\build\x64\mingw\lib\libopencv_ts247.a(ts_perf.cpp.obj):ts_perf.cpp:(.text$_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_115PerfEnvironment8TearDownEv+0xb)||undefined reference to `cv::setNumThreads(int)'|

Pls help me solve the errors.

Comment: Have you compiled opencv using cmake and then mingw make?